# Java: Deleting Specific Node (First instance of Same-Valued, if so) in Linked List with Void Return Type

Tags: java, arrays, list

I don't want to fill this space with a ton of unnecessary code, so here's the code I have already written up: http://pastebin.com/sYvrqvwH

I'm having trouble creating a method to delete a specific node (or the first instance of same-valued nodes).

I've seen a few examples of people who were trying to do the same thing, but they either used a boolean return type, or I couldn't get it to translate correctly into my code because of some extra methods.

Not saying that I want the answer, but some kind of example to follow would be nice.

Here's something I partially wrote up, but not sure if I'm even on the right track.

```
public void remove(DVD oneDVD) 
{
    DVDNode node = new DVDNode(oneDVD);
    DVDNode current;
    DVDNode previous;
    if (list == null)
    {
        list = node;
    }
        else
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the built in LinkedList?

Comment: Anyway, to remove a node, first find the node from the list that you want to remove (iterate to it). After reaching the node, set that node's previous to point to it's next. To return a void value, simply state `return;`

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja We haven't learned about the built-in LinkedList yet. We have to do it from scratch first. It sounds like my method is more or less correct minus the return, but I'm getting something about how current isn't initialized. Any idea with what I have to do there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is add an `equals()` method to your DVD. Otherwise there is no way for you to check whether a node is "same valued". The `equals()` method works by comparing all the significant fields, returning false if even one of them is different, and true if they were all equal.

Your `remove` method can then do its job:

- If `first` is null - do nothing.
- Otherwise, compare the DVD inside `first` to the given `DVD`. If they are `equal`, just assign `first`'s `next` to `first`. Done.
- Otherwise, start a loop:

  ```
  previous = first;
  for ( current = first.next; current != null; current = current.next ) {
      if ( current.dvd.equals( oneDvd ) ) {
          previous.next = current.next;
          return;
      }
      previous = current;
  }
  ```

  This loop will look for the given DVD in the list. If it finds it, it always has the previous node to connect to. It just unlinks the current node. Note that it `returns` there and doesn't continue to the end of the loop.